# count number of subdirectories of a given path

Tags: delphi, search, filesystems

I need to do some searching in the filesystem and would like to present a progress indication.
A rough approximation of that is the number of directories traversed.

```
function GetSubDirCount(Path : String): integer;
var
  Index : Integer;
  Temp : String;
  SearchRec : TSearchRec;
begin
  Result:= 0;
  Temp:= Path;

  if Path[Length(Path)] <> SysUtils.PathDelim then begin
    Path:= Path + SysUtils.PathDelim;
  end;
  Path:= Path + '*.';

  Index:= FindFirst(Path, faDirectory, SearchRec);

  while Index = 0 do begin
    if (SearchRec.Name = '.') or (SearchRec.Name = '..') then begin
      Index:= FindNext(SearchRec);
      Continue;
    end;

    Inc(Result);
    Result:= Result + GetSubDirCount(Temp + SysUtils.PathDelim + SearchRec.Name);
    Index:= FindNext(SearchRec);
  end;

  FindClose(SearchRec);
end;
```

I currently use the above code, is there a faster way?
I'm only interested in the count.
If there's a really fast way to get the number of files as well that would be a bonus.

Comment: Why are you searching for `*.`? Why not just plain `*`?

Comment: Note to self, check out the sourcecode for RTL function `GetSubDirectories`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are not specifying the Delphi version you are using, I suggest the corresponding methods from IOUtils - namely [TDirectory.GetDirectories](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetDirectories) and [TDirectory.GetFiles](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles) as they are available in recent Delphi versions.

**Update:** It is probably not the fastest way to count the number of directories and files, but if the files shall be iterated later anyway, one could as well use the result of these functions for the iteration.

Comment: I quickly changed the relevant code to make use of a TStringList, but that gave no performance gain.

Comment: Profiling with AQTime reveils that almost all of the time is spent inside the Windows routines related to FindFirst, FindNext and FindClose. Even if you can cut the SetLength calls to zero it will not show any significant performance gain.

Comment: About 500.000 files involved and the time difference is about 0.2%, which is more likely due to some tolerances.

Comment: OK, clearly paranoia on my part. It still grates with me that the code is like that but perhaps they know best! I'll clean up my mess.

Comment: +1 for `one could as well use the result of these functions for the iteration.`  The issue is that I'm doing a search later on, you have a good point about the reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Minor improvement: use const in the parameter declaration.
ex:

```
function GetSubDirCount(const Path : String): integer;
```

As Rob points out, this will not work as Path is modified in the body. I would still use this approach however, and NOT modify path in the body.  I'd have a local string var "Suffix", modify that (add optional pathdelim, and '*.'), and pass both to FindFirst:

```
FindFirst(Path+Suffix, faDirectory, SearchRec);
```

Comment: It would be no improvement since the code modifies `Path`; it can't be const.

Comment: Rob is correct. I missed that.  However, this is still an area for improvement... Amending answer accordingly.

Comment: Why would you expect this change to make any discernible difference to performance?

Comment: Passing strings as const saves overhead, as the compiler doesn't have to protect it.  See: http://delphitools.info/2010/07/28/all-hail-the-const-parameters/

Comment: @Chris I know that. It's trivial compared to the Win32 API calls that this routine makes. It only makes a different on functions that do practically nothing and are called millions of times in a tight loop.

Answer (score 0):

@Johan
Since the Windows code takes up most time, I suggest you apply the fixes suggested by other respondents, and update your code to use threads if your feel comfortable with that:

- As soon as you retrieve a subdirectory put add it to a (thread safe) list
- Have a thread look at that list and spawn worker threads do to the actual file processing per directory
- Update your progress all the time: number of dirs found/handled. This will be a bit wobbly in the beginning, but at least you can start working while Windows is still 'finding'

The 'usual' warnings apply:

- don't make your number of threads too large
- if your file processing creates new files make sure your find routines don't choke on the new output files

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't want to use threads here (the process is largely serial and I do a search straight after, which contents for the same resources (disk IO)). I was hoping that there would be some alternative for the findfirst et al API functions, because I don't want to `find` anything I just want to know how many items there are in a directory.